# Sorl-thumbnail: upgrading to new version

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I recall there was a discussion on the future of `sorl-thumbnail` and big changes coming; now that page is gone… I'm glad that the project is still being actively maintained, but I can't find any mention of backwards-compatibility problem in documentation.

So, *what do I need to do in order to update old sorl (v3.2.5) to current version (which is 10.12.1)*? Do I need to fix, say, template tag usage or settings?

Comment: Have you looked at easy-thumbnails? It's from one of the original sorl devs and I *think* it has the same API for most features, so should be pluggable

Comment: Checked out… Right now sorl seems to be more actively maintained. Also, changes to existing template markup is what I'd like to avoid; and easy-thumbnails tag syntax is definitely less compatible with older sorl's syntax then new sorl's (which maybe even is fully backwards-compatible, that's what I'm trying to figure among all other). I think switching to another thumbnail application doesn't worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sorl-thumbnail 10+ is very different from version 3.2.5-. It will require you to rewrite everything that uses sorl-thumbnail if you want to upgrade. However difficult and time consuming this might seem, its usually not such a big job. I have upgraded from the old version to new in numerous projects, some of them very big and ut has been a pretty simple and fairly quick job. Most of all, it has been worth it considering the new features with storage support, quality images using pgmagick and easy admin integration just to name a few. As mentioned the other route is probably to use easy-thumbnail which still has alot in common with the old sorl-thumbnail.

Comment: Yep, it wasn't hard, though the project itself is pretty simple. Anyway, here's what I had to do to make sorl work after updgrate: ¶ 1. Change template tags (change summary: `{% thumbnail file 100x100 crop upscale %}` becomes `{% thumbnail file "100x100" crop="center" upscale="True" %}{{ file.url }}{% endthumbnail %}`). ¶ 2. Turn `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG` setting on while working on the project.

Comment: Also, unrelated to sorl: ¶ 3. Patch PIL installation so it would support transparency in PNG images, since I can't install pgmagic on server now (few lines needed to be changed, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217869/python-pil-all-areas-of-png-with-opacity-0-have-their-opacity-set-to-1 — http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2010-October/006533.html).